# Numbering scheme for CPU affinity

Tags: vmware-esxi, central-processing-unit

In the VMware Infrastructure Client (no vCenter), under the `Resources / Advanced CPU` section of each VM's *Edit Settings* dialog, there is an option to alter the **Scheduling Affinity** of a VM.  It sets the `sched.cpu.affinity` value in the VMX file.

I believe this allows me to force a VM to only be serviced by a specific physical CPU on the host, judicious use of which *might* in some cases allow me to license a VM for one physical CPU rather than the two that are in the host.

The description of the config field in Edit Settings is as follows:

> > Hyperthreading Status: Active
> >
> > Available CPUs: 12 (logical CPUs)
>
> Select logical processor affinity for this virtual machine.
>
> Use '-' for ranges and ',' to separate values.  For example, "0,2-4,7" would indicate processors 0, 2, 3, 4 and 7.

Is it fair to assume (in this and similar cases):

- numbers 0 to 11 represent each of the physical cores (or are the 'hyperthreads' numbered too)?
- if I wanted to limit the VM to run on one of the physical CPUs, I should enter either `0-5` or `6-11` (or are these numbers in some different pattern)?

Otherwise, is there a reliable source (VIC screen, shell command, etc.) to look up the number-to-CPU mapping on any particular host?

*(For reference, the CPUs are Intel Xeon X5675 units, which are each 6-core with hyperthreading.)*

Comment: Why do you want to do this? For licensing?

Comment: @ewwhite - yes, I'm hoping to avoid an expensive second processor license afer a P2V, but appreciate that it will be subject to the letter of the EULA (which itself might be subject to the phase of the moon)

Comment: Assign the VM *one* CPU socket. That's probably the right way to handle this. What software requires the licensing?

Comment: @ewwhite - appreciated, but that would be P2V from a physical with a single quad-core to a virtual with one single-core.  I am actually defining 1 virtual socket with 4 virtual cores but, as I understand it, ESXi is free to distribute those across the host as it sees fit.

Comment: No, I said *single socket*, not single core...

Comment: @ewwhite - "I am actually defining **1 virtual socket** with 4 virtual cores but, as I understand it, ESXi is free to distribute those across the host as it sees fit"

Comment: Why does it matter how the host distributes the vCPU load across the pCPU's? If the software is licensed per socket (and not per core) and you assign it a single virtual socket (single or multi core) then why would it matter how the vCPU load is distributed across the pCPU's in the host?

Comment: @joeqwerty - Some of the more-egregious EULAs I've read do make a distinction between virtual and physical processors, and require that the software only runs on one physical processor.  However, this wasn't *supposed* to be a discussion about licensing -- can I steer it back to the technical aspect?! :-)

Comment: Gotcha. You're interested in whether or not the desired outcome is achieved. Carry on. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your software is likely licensed per (visible) CPU socket. If you configure your destination virtual machine with the appropriate socket and core count, it doesn't really matter *where* ESXi decides to schedule threads on the underlying hardware. Your software should only be concerned with what's visible to the virtual machine. In this case, a 1-socket, 4-core VM should satisfy the requirement.

See: [vCPU performance between 1 or 2 vCPU's](https://serverfault.com/questions/637792/vcpu-performance-between-1-or-2-vcpus/637802#637802)

Just like [taskset and CPU scheduling](https://serverfault.com/questions/625146/difference-between-taskset-and-cpuset/625159#625159) on Linux, you don't want to go down the path of CPU-affinities and pinning unless you have a compelling reason.

---

Edit:

The numbering is the same as [`taskset`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset). For a Westmere 6-core CPU, you will see physical and Hyperthreaded cores according to this schedule:

```
  NUMANode L#0 (P#0 32GB) + Socket L#0 + L3 L#0 (12MB)
    L2 L#0 (256KB) + L1d L#0 (32KB) + L1i L#0 (32KB) + Core L#0
      PU L#0 (P#0)
      PU L#1 (P#12)
    L2 L#1 (256KB) + L1d L#1 (32KB) + L1i L#1 (32KB) + Core L#1
      PU L#2 (P#2)
      PU L#3 (P#14)
    L2 L#2 (256KB) + L1d L#2 (32KB) + L1i L#2 (32KB) + Core L#2
      PU L#4 (P#4)
      PU L#5 (P#16)
    L2 L#3 (256KB) + L1d L#3 (32KB) + L1i L#3 (32KB) + Core L#3
      PU L#6 (P#6)
      PU L#7 (P#18)
    L2 L#4 (256KB) + L1d L#4 (32KB) + L1i L#4 (32KB) + Core L#4
      PU L#8 (P#8)
      PU L#9 (P#20)
    L2 L#5 (256KB) + L1d L#5 (32KB) + L1i L#5 (32KB) + Core L#5
      PU L#10 (P#10)
      PU L#11 (P#22)
  NUMANode L#1 (P#1 32GB) + Socket L#1 + L3 L#1 (12MB)
    L2 L#6 (256KB) + L1d L#6 (32KB) + L1i L#6 (32KB) + Core L#6
      PU L#12 (P#1)
      PU L#13 (P#13)
    L2 L#7 (256KB) + L1d L#7 (32KB) + L1i L#7 (32KB) + Core L#7
      PU L#14 (P#3)
      PU L#15 (P#15)
    L2 L#8 (256KB) + L1d L#8 (32KB) + L1i L#8 (32KB) + Core L#8
      PU L#16 (P#5)
      PU L#17 (P#17)
    L2 L#9 (256KB) + L1d L#9 (32KB) + L1i L#9 (32KB) + Core L#9
      PU L#18 (P#7)
      PU L#19 (P#19)
    L2 L#10 (256KB) + L1d L#10 (32KB) + L1i L#10 (32KB) + Core L#10
      PU L#20 (P#9)
      PU L#21 (P#21)
    L2 L#11 (256KB) + L1d L#11 (32KB) + L1i L#11 (32KB) + Core L#11
      PU L#22 (P#11)
      PU L#23 (P#23)
```

Comment: Was this generated from a command, or found in a reference article?

Comment: I just pulled the CPU topology map from one of my Westmere-based servers.

Comment: OK.  But is the number range I would enter into the field based on the `L#n` numbers in the `L2` lines (so `0-5`); on the `L#n` numbers in the `PU` lines (so `0-11`); or the `P#n` numbers in the `PU` lines (so `0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22`?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you do this. Seriously.

Comment: Noted and accepted.  That said, which set of numbers is the right one?

Comment: 0-11 are CPU socket #1, 12-23 are CPU socket #2. You can be picky and excluded Hyperthreaded cores. But that's the numbering.

Comment: Thanks.  For completeness, running `esxcfg-info -w` from the shell will list each physical CPU as a `CpuPackage`, under which it shows each thread as a `CpuImpl` -- the `ID` property of that appears to marry with `0-11` and `12-23` also, so it stands that one could use this for reference on any arbitrary host.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it fair to assume (in this and similar cases):
>
> - numbers 0 to 11 represent each of the physical cores (or are the    'hyperthreads' numbered too)?

Yes and yes HT are included

> - if I wanted to limit the VM to run on    one of the physical CPUs, I should enter either 0-5 or 6-11 (or are    these numbers in some
>     different pattern)?

Yes, you got it in one!

Comment: "Yes and yes HT are included" - does that mean two six-core hyperthreads are actually `0-11` and `12-23`?

Comment: Yes, exactly that